# Function not returning value, but cout displays it

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been learning C++ for a bit and tried my hand at making a simple function that returns the area of a room. The return statement doesn't output the value, however using cout I can see the result. Am I missing something here?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int Area(int x, int y);

int main()
{
  int len;
  int wid;
  int area;
  cout << "Hello, enter the length and width of your room." << endl;
  cin >> len >> wid;
  cout << "The area of your room is: ";
  Area(len, wid);
  return 0;
}

int Area(int len, int wid)
{
  int answer = ( len * wid );
  return answer;
}
```

Comment: Can you please copy-paste the output you get from running that program, because there should not be any output from calling `Area`.

Comment: just a typo, perhaps you mean: `cout << "The area of your room is: " <<   Area(len, wid);`

Comment: @codekaizer I think this is not a typo, let me explain. I've seen multiple time students unable to grasp the conceptual difference between returning a value and printing a value. This is due, I think, to poor education regarding development to beginners: they are often asked to "return" the result of a computation by printing it on screen. Those exercises are often written as a relatively short but monolithic `main()`. Hence the confusion between `return` and `std::ostream::operator<<`.

Comment: There are many terms that refer to different things in different contexts. One distinction that can be confusing at first is that between a *function's* "output", which usually means the value that the function returns to its caller, and a *program's* "output", which is the things that are printed on the terminal.

Comment: @YSC, i agree with you.

Answer (score 8):

`std::cout` is used to *print* data on screen. Functions only *return* values, so the `Area` function will return the value which is to be passed in `std::ostream::operator<<` function to print it. You need to write:

```
std::cout << Area(len, wid) << "\n";
```

Comment: do you mind my edit? If you do, you can improve it or rollback it. Hope its good.

Answer (score 7):

`return` doesn't print anything, and you shouldn't expect it to. All it does is *return* a value from the function. You can then do whatever you want with that value, including printing it, or assigning it to a variable:

```
// Does not print:
Area(len, wid);

// Does print:
int result = Area(len, wid);
std::cout << result << "\n";

// Does print:
std::cout << Area(len, wid) << "\n";
```

<sup>Imagine the chaos if every function in a massive codebase suddenly started printing its return value...</sup>